# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "movies"

Tags: postgresql

I am new to SQL and need to query a database to extract certain information before I can import it into another software I am familiar with to analyse the data. This query was sent to me by a friend who I don't have access to at the moment, and I cannot figure out why it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "movies"
LINE 8: FROM (SELECT movies.movieid
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT innerselect.movieid
       ,innerselect.title
       ,innerselect.year
       ,innerselect.imdbid
       ,innerselect.budget[1] AS budget_currency
       ,TO_NUMBER(innerselect.budget[2], '999999999999990.00') AS budget_total
       ,innerselect.businesstext
FROM (SELECT movies.movieid
       ,movies.title
       ,movies.year
       ,movies.imdbid
       ,business.businesstext
       ,regexp_matches(business.businesstext, '^BT:[ ](USD)[ ](-?(?!0)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+))', 'g') AS budget -- creates a PostgreSQL Array which contains the content matched with the RegEx Groups FROM movies LEFT JOIN business ON movies.movieid=business.movieid WHERE movies.movieid > 2753500
) AS innerselect
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you put the FROM on the same line as the comment, so the FROM clause was ignored.

```
SELECT innerselect.movieid
       ,innerselect.title
       ,innerselect.year
       ,innerselect.imdbid
       ,innerselect.budget[1] AS budget_currency
       ,TO_NUMBER(innerselect.budget[2], '999999999999990.00') AS budget_total
       ,innerselect.businesstext
FROM (SELECT movies.movieid
       ,movies.title
       ,movies.year
       ,movies.imdbid
       ,business.businesstext
       ,regexp_matches(business.businesstext, '^BT:[ ](USD)[ ](-?(?!0)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+))', 'g') AS budget -- creates a PostgreSQL Array which contains the content matched with the RegEx Groups
      FROM movies LEFT JOIN business ON movies.movieid=business.movieid WHERE movies.movieid > 2753500
) AS innerselect
```